# Animate layer image changing source (StaticImage)

Tags: openlayers

I need recreate animated radar (in timeline) with openlayers 3(or 4).
 I try changed source on StaticImage, and work ok!.
But when the image comes out a little bit from the screen, the image does not refresh.
My code:

```
var extent = [-58.51557, -30.244304187, -63.5245788523, -35.24082];
//var extent = undefined;

var source0 = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    url: '/static/images/setDatos1.png',
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    imageExtent: extent
});
var source1 = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    url: '/static/images/setDatos2.png',
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    imageExtent: extent
});

var sources = [source0, source1]

var radar_rosario_layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    opacity: 1,
    visible: true,
    extent: undefined

});
radar_rosario_layer.setZIndex(9000);

var val = 1;
setInterval(function () {
            if (val != 1) {
                val = 1
            } else {
                val = 0
            }       
            radar_rosario_layer.setSource(sources[val]); 
        }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this extent is wrong. Extent should be like [ minx , miny , maxx , maxy ]. For example ; [-63.5245788523, -35.24082,-58.51557 , -30.244304187]